# Chrome prevent update of all tabs, when re-open browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Usually I have more than 30 tabs, and when I close and re-open browser, Chrome tries to update all of them. It`s very slow. I need all the tabs would be reopened (only link at the tab), but would be updated only if I click on it. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg) does something like what you say you want I believe.